# No Output in my php code

Tags: php, html, sql

Please help me.. I don't know why there is no output in my PHP code.. Below is my index.php code

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="search.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name"number" placeholder="Search...."><br/>
<input type = "submit" value="Search">

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is my search.php.

```
<html>
<body>
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 
mysql_select_db("login");

$initial = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['initial']);

$find_videos = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `sigup` WHERE `initial` LIKE '%initial%'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($find_videos))
{
$name = $row['name'];
echo "$name<br/ >";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure your column name is `sigup` ? I doubt it is `signup`.

Comment: On what basis do you assume that *search.php* should produce any output?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran it should be `table` name :)

Comment: `echo mysql_error()` and `echo mysql_num_rows()` after the query.

Comment: Alert!!! mysql_* functions are depreciated http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/829533

Comment: yeh im sure that's sigup not "signup"

Answer (score 0):

```
 mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `sigup` WHERE `initial` LIKE '%$initial%'");

 <input type="text" name="initial" placeholder="Search....">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="search.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="initial" placeholder="Search...."><br/>
<input type = "submit" value="Search">

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**search.php**

```
<html>
<body>
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 
mysql_select_db("login");

$initial = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['initial']);

$find_videos = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `sigup` WHERE `initial` LIKE '%$initial%'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($find_videos))
{
$name = $row['name'];
echo "$name<br/ >";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but this the another error "Notice: Undefined index: initial in C:\wamp\www\ralph\search.php on line 9" .. :((

Comment: what is initial in search.php

Comment: i changed the name of the button <input type="text" name="number" placeholder="Search...."><br/> ........ and $initial = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['number']); i guess that ($_POST['number']) is the name of button..

Comment: but it say's "Notice: Undefined index: number in C:\wamp\www\ralph\search.php on line 6" .. :((

Comment: try to remove mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: please change'%$initial%' instead of '%initial%'.definatly show output.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <html>
    <body>

    <form action="search.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="number" placeholder="Search...."><br/>
     <input type = "submit" value="Search">

    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

search.php

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 
    mysql_select_db("login");
    $initial = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['number']);
    $find_videos = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sigup  WHERE initial LIKE '%initial%'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($find_videos))
    {
    $name = $row['name'];
    echo "$name";
    }
    ?>
    </body>
   </html>
```